# Making data ready for FP growth in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to implement [FP growth algorith](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth). I have data in following format:

```
Food        rank
apple       1
caterpillar 1
banana      2
monkey      2
dog         3
bone        3
oath        3
```

How do I transform it into `[[apple,caterpillar],[banana,monkey],[dog,bone,oath]]`?

Comment: What does the rank represent ? FPGrowth takes a sequence of "events" as a list. Thus according to your output, this is what FPGrowth will read after event 1, event apple happend then event caterpillar. So are you sure that you want that output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is a `DataFrame`, we first convert it to an `rdd`, then define the `key`'s, use them to group your data and finally `map` the values into a `list` and extract them. We can do this two ways, either use `groupByKey()`:

```
(df.rdd
 .map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
 .groupByKey()
 .mapValues(list)
 .values())
```

Or use `reduceByKey()`, which is going to be more efficient:

```
(df.rdd
 .map(lambda x: (x[1],[x[0]]))
 .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
 .values())
```

**Data:**

```
df = sc.parallelize([("apple", 1),
                     ("caterpillar", 1),
                     ("banana", 2),
                     ("monkey", 2),
                     ("dog", 3),
                     ("bone", 3),
                     ("oath", 3)]).toDF(["Food", "rank"])
```

Comment: how do I remove duplicate from food?

Comment: for example if I have two apple with rank 1. I want to have single apple only.

Comment: `df.distinct()`